# How to change the wifi setting if not able to connect to device

Tags: wifi, connection

I forgot what was wifi setting of my respberry -3. I want to connect that, but my device is not connecting to the wifi. Is there any way I can change the wifi setting of my device. I am able to mount the flash of my device on linux.

Comment: can you telnet or ssh to the RPi using the ethernet port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address), specifically "Headless WiFi setup".

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the ESSID and password, you can edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant`.  The corresponding fields there are very clear:

```
network={
    ssid="___"
    psk="___"
}
```

"psk" refers to the password.  Don't change anything else, and make a backup copy of the file before you change it.

Comment: How to get to /etc directory, I don't have access to my device. If I mount that I see only these files 



COPYING.linux   bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb  fixup.dat   overlays
LICENCE.broadcom  bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb fixup_cd.dat   start.elf
LICENSE.oracle   bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb  fixup_db.dat   start_cd.elf
bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb  bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb  fixup_x.dat   start_db.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb  bootcode.bin   issue.txt   start_x.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb  cmdline.txt   kernel.img

Comment: In your question you wrote, *"I am able to mount the flash of my device on linux"*.  The root filesystem containing `etc` is on the second partition of the card.  However, if you are **not** using linux you will not see that partition unless you install software that can access `ext4` filesystems.

Comment: After mounting I see a boot device and it contains the files i mentioned above. I don't think is proper mount.

Comment: Your card contains two partitions: _boot_ and _rootfs_. You have have to access your _rootfs_ to change the config file. (If you are not able to mount your card get yourself a real OS!)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the suggestions from the comments, you wrote:

> I am able to mount the flash of my device on linux.

You do not tell us what **O**perating **S**ystem you are using so I assume it is *Raspbian*. This OS is installed on two partitions: the first partition is labeled **boot** and is formated as `vfat`, the second partition is labeled **rootfs** and is formated as `ext4`. You can show it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo blkid
```

The linux OS you are using is able to read `ext4` file systems so you can mount the second partition with (if for example the SD Card is attached to */dev/sdb*):

```
rpi ~$ mkdir rootfs/
rpi ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 rootfs/
```

Now you can access `rootfs/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and modify it as *@goldilocks* suggested in his answer. If you have done, finish with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo umount rootfs/
rpi ~$ rmdir rootfs/
```

and boot the SD Card with your RasPi.